# how to check login status on clicking on the images

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I wanted to check login status on clicking the images. When I click on the image
and if user did not login then show dialog box "please login first".
I stored login status in session variable.

Here is my controller code:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($k->result() as $row)  {
   if($i==3){
    echo "<tr style='border-left: 1px solid #000; padding: 25px 0;'>";
    $i=0;
    }   
   echo "<td style='border-left: 1px solid #000;border-bottom: solid 1px 
   black;border-right: 1px solid #000;padding: 25px 0;'><align = center ; 
   background-color:white;>
   <div class='pure-u-1-1 box'><a href='javascript:void(0);' 
    onclick='login();' data-variable='".$row->cityname."' class='topopup'>
 <img class='cityimg' src='http://localhost/Sell_Punch/assets/images/city/".
  ($row>cityname).".jpg' width='150' height='100'  ></a></div>
 <div  align=center style='padding:15px; backgroundcolor:#004b79;; color:white'> ".$row->cityname." </div>

        </td>";
    $i=$i+1;
    }           
    ?>
```

javascript code

```
    <script>
    function login()
  {

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
    return true;
    }
     else
     {
       alert("Please login first!");;


     }

     }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to put you script in `<?php ?>` tag..

```
<script>
    function login() {
    <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) { ?>
            return true;
    <?php } else { ?>
            alert("Please login first!");;
    <?php } ?>
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call PHP in javascript. That won't work. Put the php in some PHP tags:

```
<script>
    function login()
  {
    var status = '<?= $this->session->userdata('logged_in') ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?>';
    if(status == 'yes') {
        return true;
    }
     else
     {
       alert("Please login first!");;
     }

     }
  </script>
```